# Handling cross region requests in AWS EC2 and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

We have EC2 instance hosting a web application and another RDS Server with SQL Server. Both are in US-WEST-2 region. The web site has a single page with button. When user clicks the button it UPDATES a table using a stored procedure. This update is not a complex updates, it selects a single row based on criteria and then updates that row. However table has more than 200K rows.

When users from the US access application they don't seems to have any issue. However, we have couple of users access the application from Africa. Users from Africa,however experience slow access and for them page crash every now and then.

When i checked the log, it always SQL timeout. Total number of users from US and Africa are not more than 10 so even if all clicked the button at the same time SQL Server should be able to handle 10 users.

(On our dev server I have done load testing with 100 users and I never got SQL timeout)

I understand that there will be latency for Users from Africa while accessing application. However, i am not able to understand why only those users seems have SQL timeout issue?

Is there any settings/configuration in AWS that we need to check for cross region requests? Does EC2 handles request differently when it comes from different continent/region? I understand its hard to pinpoint exact problem here but I am looking for suggestions especially related to AWS configuration for cross region requests.

Comment: Maybe your stored procedure has some funny logic depending on the location?

Comment: No the stored procedure has no funny logic based on location

Comment: If your web application runs in same region as your RDS instance, there's no reason why requests to web server from different continent make any change, except for the query itself. Have you tried profiling your SQL query?